# wireshark: Capture Data Layer Only

Tags: wireshark, encryption

Is there a way to capture only the data layer and disregard the upper layers in wireshark? If not, is there a different packet dump utility that can do this? PREFERABLY 1 file per packet!

What I am looking for: A utility that dumps only the data (the payload) layer to a file.

This is programming related...! What I really want to do is to compare all of the datagrams in order to start to understand a third party encoding/protocol. Ideally, and what would be great, would be a hex compare utility that compares multiple files!

Comment: Stackoverflow is for asking programming questions. Until the IT version of SO is ready, you may find more help for this at one of the sites listed here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/321618/where-can-i-ask-questions-that-arent-programming-questions

Comment: This **is** a programming related question, you are only assuming that it is IT exclusive. You know what they say about assuming.....

Comment: I agree that wireshark can be used to usually troubleshoot programming issue. I would hold that more often it is not.

Comment: I am using it to help decipher third party and closed source encoding (which is not illegal). Additionally this is a must to plan out the requirements. SO covers all stages of software development lifecycle and anything directly related to any of its stages.

Comment: Additionally, the payload/daya layer is where APPLICATION LOGIC goes and has nothing to do with networking. Hence why it is also called the application layer.

Comment: So perhaps explain that in the question. Explain that you want to look at the app data from a third party app so you can plan the app that you are writing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should try right-clicking on a packet and select "Follow TCP Stream". Then you can save the TCP communication into a raw file for further processing. This way you won't get all the TCP/IP protocoll junk.

Comment: Capital idea! This might just be exactly what I need.

Comment: cool stuff, pity it doesnt take wireshark packet filtering into account.

Answer (score 0):

There is a function to limit capture size in Wireshark, but it seems that 68bytes is the smallest value.  There are options to starting new files after a certain number of kilo, mega, gigabytes, but again the smallest is 1-kilobyte, so probably not useful.

I would suggest looking at the pcap library and rolling your own.  I've done this in the past using the PERL Net::Pcap library, but it could easily be done it other languages too.

If you have Unix/Linux available you might also look into tcpdump.  You can limit amount of data captured with -s.  For example "-s 14" would typically get you the Ethernet header, which I assume is what you mean by the datalink layer.  There are also options for controlling how often files are created by specifying file size with -C.  So theoretically if you set the file size to the capture size, you'll get one file per packet.

Answer (score 0):

Using `tshark` I was able to print data only,  by decoding as telnet and printing field telnet.data

```
tshark -r file.pcap -d tcp.port==80,telnet -T fields -e telnet.data



GET /test.js HTTP/1.1\x0d\x0a,User-Agent: curl/7.35.0\x0d\x0a,Host: 127.0.0.1\x0d\x0a,Accept: */*\x0d\x0a,\x0d\x0a

HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found\x0d\x0a,Server: nginx/1.4.6 (Ubuntu)\x0d\x0a,Date: Fri, 15 Jan 2016 11:32:58 GMT\x0d\x0a,Content-Type: text/html\x0d\x0a,Content-Length: 177\x0d\x0a,Connection: keep-alive\x0d\x0a,\x0d\x0a,<html>\x0d\x0a,<head><title>404 Not Found</title></head>\x0d\x0a,<body bgcolor=\"white\">\x0d\x0a,<center><h1>404 Not Found</h1></center>\x0d\x0a,<hr><center>nginx/1.4.6 (Ubuntu)</center>\x0d\x0a,</body>\x0d\x0a,</html>\x0d\x0a
```

Not perfect but it was good enough for what I needed, I hope it helps some one.